# How Do I Write My First Appium Test For iOS

Tags: java, ios, selenium, automated-tests, appium

I have set up all of the prerequisites to run an Appium test on my mac computer, but I cannot figure out how to run my first Appium test.  I am having trouble writing my test in Java.  The perfect thing would be a file that I could just put on my computer, that, when run, would open the iOS simulator and press some buttons.  I know Selenium well so I could figure out the rest myself.  I also have several test apps on my computer

But any help with writing the actual test file itself (Java preferred) would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

To run iOS tests, you can follow these steps :

(**Note** : I am using Java language here in Eclipse IDE and using Appium app):

1. Create a new java project in Eclipse.
2. Import jar files : Selenium Server (formerly the Selenium RC Server) version and required client driver (according to your language choice) which can be downloaded [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/). (To import : Right click on your project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add External JARs. Add all three selenium jar files here.)
3. [Download](https://bitbucket.org/appium/appium.app/downloads/) Appium app and launch.
4. You can run your test scripts either in simulator or on real device. To run scripts on real iOS device, you will need 'deviceName', 'platformVersion', 'UDID' (Device ID) and 'Bundle ID' (Application Bundle ID) and absolute path to the .ipa.
5. To run scripts on iOS simulator , you will need 'deviceName', 'platformVersion', path to .app and 'Bundle ID' of your app.
6. Choose capabilties in Appium app and mention the same in your script based on whether you are testing on simulator or on device.
7. Launch Appium server and then run your script.

All Appium server capabilities which can be used can be found [here](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-server-capabilities).

You can refer to my blog post [here](http://smritituteja.in/ios-mobile-automation-using-appium/) as well for more details to execute a sample basic script.

Comment: @NatureofOrigin: please try now..it should be accessible.